# Adding a counter to a specific string using unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to add a counter to a specific string using unix, I have tried some sed and awk commands but I can't seem to do it properly.

My input file is:

```
Event_ A     D       L       K
Event_ B     P       R
Event_ C     F       I
Event_ J     K
M
N
O
Event_ Q     S
X
Y
Z
G
T
```

What I'm hoping to get is:

```
Event_00000001    A     D       L       K
Event_00000002    B     P       R
Event_00000003    C     F       I
Event_00000004    J     K
M
N
O
Event_00000005    Q     S
X
Y
Z
G
T
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^Event/{$1=sprintf("%s%06d", $1,++counter)}1' yourfile
```

If fields are delimited by `\t`(Tab),

```
awk -F"\t" '/^Event/{$1=sprintf("%s%06d", $1,++counter)}1' OFS='\t' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk '/^Event/{$1=sprintf("%s%06d", $1,++counter)}1' file
Event_000001 A D L K
Event_000002 B P R
Event_000003 C F I
Event_000004 J K
M
N
O
Event_000005 Q S
X
Y
Z
G
T
```